# Solving a particular differential eigenvalue equation with singular behavior

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve a particular differential equation, using NDSolve. The equation is as follows:
$\frac{d}{dz} \left( (1+z^2)z \frac{dg}{dz} \right) = - \lambda (1+z^2)^{-1/3}zg(z)$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. 
I have attempted to solve it using a series expansion and a shooting method, as follows.

First I rewrite the equation in terms of $f = g(z)/z^2$,

$f''(z) + \frac{1+3z^2}{z(1+z^2)} f'(z) =- \lambda \frac{z}{(1+z^2)^{4/3}}$.

Then I define a new variable $z=e^{t}$, which then allows me to rewrite the equation as

$g''(t) - \frac{4+2z^2}{1+z^2} g'(t) + \frac{4}{1+z^2}g(t)=- \lambda \frac{z}{(1+z^2)^{4/3}}g(t)$.

I then solve the equation for $f(z)$, using initial conditions that come from the equation for $g(t)$.

Specifically, I do

```
ParametricNDSolve[{f''[z] + (3*z^2 + 1)/(z*(1 + z^2))*f'[z] + \[Lambda]*
     f[z]/(1 + z^2)^(4/3) == 0, f[zin] == g[zin], 
  f'[zin] == g'[zin]}, f, {z, 0, zmax}, {\[Lambda]}]
```

where

```
g[Z_] := Sum[\[Alpha][[l + 1]] Z^((-2 l)/3 - 2), {l, 0, 10}];
g'[Z_] := 
  Sum[(-(2/3) l - 2)*\[Alpha][[l + 1]] Z^((-2 l)/3 - 3), {l, 0, 10}];
```

and where `\Alpha[l]` is defined recursively as follows:

```
C[y_] := -((2 + 4*y^3)/(1 + y^3)) ;
D[y_, \[Lambda]_] := (4*y^3)/(y^3 + 1) + (\[Lambda]*y)/(1 + y^3)^(4/
   3) ;
c = Table[SeriesCoefficient[C3[y], {y, 0, n}], {n, 0, 10}]  ;
d = Table[
   SeriesCoefficient[D3[y, \[Lambda]], {y, 0, n}], {n, 0, 10}] ;
\[Alpha] = Table[0, {n, 0, 10}] ;
\[Alpha][[1]] = 1 ;
Do[\[Alpha][[
    l + 1]] = (4/9 l^2 + 
      2 l/3)^-1*(2/
       3 (Sum[k*\[Alpha][[k + 1]]*c[[l + 1 - k]], {k, l - 1}]) - 
      Sum[\[Alpha][[k + 1]]*d[[l + 1 - k]], {k, 0, l - 1}]), {l, 1, 
   10}] ;
```

I set zmax = 1000000
zin = 10000.

I then find values for $\lambda$ using FindRoot. For example, the lowest value I get is 2.51. Then I re-reun the code with that value, using NDSolve instead of ParametricNDSolve.

Now here is my problem. The solutions I get for g(z) are very badly behaved as $z \rightarrow 0$. I get a "singularity or stiff system suspected" error. And I cannot seem to get any solution for negative $z$. If I define the interval as {-zmax,zmax} in NDSolve, I still only get a solution for positive z.

Question: can someone think of a better way to solve this equation, and in particular, to extend it to negative z?

Comment: All this seems unnecessarily complicated.  What are the boundary conditions for the original ODE?

Comment: I should have mentioned this, yes. The boundary condition is that following integral should not blow up, $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{z (g(z))^2}{(1+z^2)^{1/3}} dz$.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a sufficient boundary condition.